# Show the tooltip inside a div in a D3 stacked area chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="d3@3.5.3" data-semver="3.5.3" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.3/d3.js"></script>
  <style>
    body {
      font: 10px sans-serif;
    }
    .axis path,
    .axis line {
      fill: none;
      stroke: #000;
      shape-rendering: crispEdges;
    }
    .x.axis path {
      display: none;
    }
    .line {
      fill: none;
      stroke: steelblue;
      stroke-width: 1.5px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <script>
    var myData = "date New York San Francisco Austin\n\
20111001 63.4 62.7 72.2\n\
20111002 58.0 59.9 67.7\n\
20111003 53.3 59.1 69.4\n\
20111004 55.7 58.8 68.0\n\
20111005 64.2 58.7 72.4\n\
20111006 58.8 57.0 77.0\n\
20111007 57.9 56.7 82.3\n\
20111008 61.8 56.8 78.9\n\
20111009 69.3 56.7 68.8\n\
20111010 71.2 60.1 68.7\n\
20111011 68.7 61.1 70.3\n\
20111012 61.8 61.5 75.3\n\
20111013 63.0 64.3 76.6\n\
20111014 66.9 67.1 66.6\n\
20111015 61.7 64.6 68.0\n\
20111016 61.8 61.6 70.6\n\
20111017 62.8 61.1 71.1\n\
20111018 60.8 59.2 70.0\n\
20111019 62.1 58.9 61.6\n\
20111020 65.1 57.2 57.4\n\
20111021 55.6 56.4 64.3\n\
20111022 54.4 60.7 72.4\n";

    var margin = {
        top: 20,
        right: 80,
        bottom: 30,
        left: 50
      },
      width = 500 - margin.left - margin.right,
      height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y%m%d").parse;

    var x = d3.time.scale()
      .range([0, width]);

    var y = d3.scale.linear()
      .range([height, 0]);

    var color = d3.scale.category20();

    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(x)
      .orient("bottom");

    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(y)
      .orient("left");

    var line = d3.svg.line()
      .interpolate("basis")
      .x(function(d) {
        return x(d.date);
      })
      .y(function(d) {
        return y(d.temperature);
      });

    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
      .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
      .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    var data = d3.tsv.parse(myData);

    color.domain(d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key) {
      return key !== "date";
    }));

    data.forEach(function(d) {
      d.date = parseDate(d.date);
    });

    var cities = color.domain().map(function(name) {
      return {
        name: name,
        values: data.map(function(d) {
          return {
            date: d.date,
            temperature: +d[name]
          };
        })
      };
    });

    x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) {
      return d.date;
    }));

    y.domain([
      d3.min(cities, function(c) {
        return d3.min(c.values, function(v) {
          return v.temperature;
        });
      }),
      d3.max(cities, function(c) {
        return d3.max(c.values, function(v) {
          return v.temperature;
        });
      })
    ]);

    var legend = svg.selectAll('g')
      .data(cities)
      .enter()
      .append('g')
      .attr('class', 'legend');

    legend.append('rect')
      .attr('x', width - 20)
      .attr('y', function(d, i) {
        return i * 20;
      })
      .attr('width', 10)
      .attr('height', 10)
      .style('fill', function(d) {
        return color(d.name);
      });

    legend.append('text')
      .attr('x', width - 8)
      .attr('y', function(d, i) {
        return (i * 20) + 9;
      })
      .text(function(d) {
        return d.name;
      });

    svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

    svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
      .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Temperature (ºF)");

    var city = svg.selectAll(".city")
      .data(cities)
      .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "city");

    city.append("path")
      .attr("class", "line")
      .attr("d", function(d) {
        return line(d.values);
      })
      .style("stroke", function(d) {
        return color(d.name);
      });

    city.append("text")
      .datum(function(d) {
        return {
          name: d.name,
          value: d.values[d.values.length - 1]
        };
      })
      .attr("transform", function(d) {
        return "translate(" + x(d.value.date) + "," + y(d.value.temperature) + ")";
      })
      .attr("x", 3)
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .text(function(d) {
        return d.name;
      });

    var mouseG = svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "mouse-over-effects");

    mouseG.append("path") // this is the black vertical line to follow mouse
      .attr("class", "mouse-line")
      .style("stroke", "black")
      .style("stroke-width", "1px")
      .style("opacity", "0");

    var lines = document.getElementsByClassName('line');

    var mousePerLine = mouseG.selectAll('.mouse-per-line')
      .data(cities)
      .enter()
      .append("g")
      .attr("class", "mouse-per-line");

    mousePerLine.append("circle")
      .attr("r", 7)
      .style("stroke", function(d) {
        return color(d.name);
      })
      .style("fill", "none")
      .style("stroke-width", "1px")
      .style("opacity", "0");

    mousePerLine.append("text")
      .attr("transform", "translate(10,3)");

    mouseG.append('svg:rect') // append a rect to catch mouse movements on canvas
      .attr('width', width) // can't catch mouse events on a g element
      .attr('height', height)
      .attr('fill', 'none')
      .attr('pointer-events', 'all')
      .on('mouseout', function() { // on mouse out hide line, circles and text
        d3.select(".mouse-line")
          .style("opacity", "0");
        d3.selectAll(".mouse-per-line circle")
          .style("opacity", "0");
        d3.selectAll(".mouse-per-line text")
          .style("opacity", "0");
      })
      .on('mouseover', function() { // on mouse in show line, circles and text
        d3.select(".mouse-line")
          .style("opacity", "1");
        d3.selectAll(".mouse-per-line circle")
          .style("opacity", "1");
        d3.selectAll(".mouse-per-line text")
          .style("opacity", "1");
      })
      .on('mousemove', function() { // mouse moving over canvas
        var mouse = d3.mouse(this);
        d3.select(".mouse-line")
          .attr("d", function() {
            var d = "M" + mouse[0] + "," + height;
            d += " " + mouse[0] + "," + 0;
            return d;
          });

        d3.selectAll(".mouse-per-line")
          .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
            console.log(width / mouse[0])
            var xDate = x.invert(mouse[0]),
              bisect = d3.bisector(function(d) {
                return d.date;
              }).right;
            idx = bisect(d.values, xDate);

            var beginning = 0,
              end = lines[i].getTotalLength(),
              target = null;

            while (true) {
              target = Math.floor((beginning + end) / 2);
              pos = lines[i].getPointAtLength(target);
              if ((target === end || target === beginning) && pos.x !== mouse[0]) {
                break;
              }
              if (pos.x > mouse[0]) end = target;
              else if (pos.x < mouse[0]) beginning = target;
              else break; //position found
            }

            d3.select(this).select('text')
              .text(y.invert(pos.y).toFixed(2));

            return "translate(" + mouse[0] + "," + pos.y + ")";
          });
      });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Hello. I am new to D3, Please forgive me if I ask something stupid. I have been trying to show the tooltip of the stacked area chart on hover inside a rectangular div rather than showing beside each line. Till now I have understood and achieved this, but I am unable to add a rectangular div to the tooltip to show my data on hover inside it. Please help me. Thanks for any advance help.

Comment: Rach , are you trying to display border to the hover values??

Comment: Your question is not clear...the tooltips are coming, may be a screen shot of what you want to achieve..

Comment: Sorry for inconvenience. Actually I want to display all the values that get displayed on hover on the line inside a particular rectangular box rather than printing on the area boundary that is getting happened as of now. The condition is there should be a single rectangular box to display all the values of the stacked area chart rather than creating individual box to each value.

Comment: Rach, both values should be displayed in one single rectangular box right?

Comment: Thank you Naga Sai for your response. Yes exactly, I want to display border to the hover values but that should be a single border for all values rather than individual border for each value on hover.

Comment: Yes Naga Sir, whatever values I am getting on hover should be displayed inside a single rectangular box.

Comment: I am new to D3 so facing issues. Please help me. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="d3@3.5.3" data-semver="3.5.3" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.3/d3.js"></script>
  <style>
    body {
      font: 10px sans-serif;
    }
    .axis path,
    .axis line {
      fill: none;
      stroke: #000;
      shape-rendering: crispEdges;
    }
    .x.axis path {
      display: none;
    }
    .line {
      fill: none;
      stroke: steelblue;
      stroke-width: 1.5px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <script>
    var myData = "date New York San Francisco Austin\n\
20111001 63.4 62.7 72.2\n\
20111002 58.0 59.9 67.7\n\
20111003 53.3 59.1 69.4\n\
20111004 55.7 58.8 68.0\n\
20111005 64.2 58.7 72.4\n\
20111006 58.8 57.0 77.0\n\
20111007 57.9 56.7 82.3\n\
20111008 61.8 56.8 78.9\n\
20111009 69.3 56.7 68.8\n\
20111010 71.2 60.1 68.7\n\
20111011 68.7 61.1 70.3\n\
20111012 61.8 61.5 75.3\n\
20111013 63.0 64.3 76.6\n\
20111014 66.9 67.1 66.6\n\
20111015 61.7 64.6 68.0\n\
20111016 61.8 61.6 70.6\n\
20111017 62.8 61.1 71.1\n\
20111018 60.8 59.2 70.0\n\
20111019 62.1 58.9 61.6\n\
20111020 65.1 57.2 57.4\n\
20111021 55.6 56.4 64.3\n\
20111022 54.4 60.7 72.4\n";

    var margin = {
        top: 20,
        right: 80,
        bottom: 30,
        left: 50
      },
      width = 500 - margin.left - margin.right,
      height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y%m%d").parse;

    var x = d3.time.scale()
      .range([0, width]);

    var y = d3.scale.linear()
      .range([height, 0]);

    var color = d3.scale.category20();

    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(x)
      .orient("bottom");

    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(y)
      .orient("left");

    var line = d3.svg.line()
      .interpolate("basis")
      .x(function(d) {
        return x(d.date);
      })
      .y(function(d) {
        return y(d.temperature);
      });

    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
      .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
      .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    var data = d3.tsv.parse(myData);

    color.domain(d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key) {
      return key !== "date";
    }));

    data.forEach(function(d) {
      d.date = parseDate(d.date);
    });

    var cities = color.domain().map(function(name) {
      return {
        name: name,
        values: data.map(function(d) {
          return {
            date: d.date,
            temperature: +d[name]
          };
        })
      };
    });

    x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) {
      return d.date;
    }));

    y.domain([
      d3.min(cities, function(c) {
        return d3.min(c.values, function(v) {
          return v.temperature;
        });
      }),
      d3.max(cities, function(c) {
        return d3.max(c.values, function(v) {
          return v.temperature;
        });
      })
    ]);

    var legend = svg.selectAll('g')
      .data(cities)
      .enter()
      .append('g')
      .attr('class', 'legend');

    legend.append('rect')
      .attr('x', width - 20)
      .attr('y', function(d, i) {
        return i * 20;
      })
      .attr('width', 10)
      .attr('height', 10)
      .style('fill', function(d) {
        return color(d.name);
      });

    legend.append('text')
      .attr('x', width - 8)
      .attr('y', function(d, i) {
        return (i * 20) + 9;
      })
      .text(function(d) {
        return d.name;
      });

    svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

    svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
      .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Temperature (ºF)");

    var city = svg.selectAll(".city")
      .data(cities)
      .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "city");

    city.append("path")
      .attr("class", "line")
      .attr("d", function(d) {
        return line(d.values);
      })
      .style("stroke", function(d) {
        return color(d.name);
      });

    city.append("text")
      .datum(function(d) {
        return {
          name: d.name,
          value: d.values[d.values.length - 1]
        };
      })
      .attr("transform", function(d) {
        return "translate(" + x(d.value.date) + "," + y(d.value.temperature) + ")";
      })
      .attr("x", 3)
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .text(function(d) {
        return d.name;
      });

    var mouseG = svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "mouse-over-effects");

    mouseG.append("path") // this is the black vertical line to follow mouse
      .attr("class", "mouse-line")
      .style("stroke", "black")
      .style("stroke-width", "1px")
      .style("opacity", "0");

    var lines = document.getElementsByClassName('line');

    var mousePerLine = mouseG.selectAll('.mouse-per-line')
      .data(cities)
      .enter()
      .append("g")
      .attr("class", "mouse-per-line");

    mousePerLine.append("rect")
      .attr("width", width / 2)
      .attr("height", 30)
      .style("padding", "5px")
      .style("stroke", function(d) {
        return color(d.name);
      })
      .style("fill", function(d) {
        return color(d.name);
      })
      .style("stroke-width", "1px")
      .style("opacity", "0")
      .attr('x', 10);


    mousePerLine.append("circle")
      .attr("r", 5)
      .style("stroke", function(d) {
        return color(d.name);
      })
      .style("fill", function(d) {
        return color(d.name);
      })
      .style("stroke-width", "1px")
      .style("opacity", "0");

    mousePerLine.append("text")
      .attr("transform", "translate(15,13)");

    mouseG.append('svg:rect') // append a rect to catch mouse movements on canvas
      .attr('width', width) // can't catch mouse events on a g element
      .attr('height', height)
      .attr('fill', 'none')
      .attr('pointer-events', 'all')
      .on('mouseout', function() { // on mouse out hide line, circles and text
        d3.select(".mouse-line")
          .style("opacity", "0");
        d3.selectAll(".mouse-per-line rect")
          .style("opacity", "0");
        d3.selectAll(".mouse-per-line circle")
          .style("opacity", "0");
        d3.selectAll(".mouse-per-line text")
          .style("opacity", "0");
      })
      .on('mouseover', function() { // on mouse in show line, circles and text
        d3.select(".mouse-line")
          .style("opacity", "1");
        d3.selectAll(".mouse-per-line rect")
          .style("opacity", "0.5");
        d3.selectAll(".mouse-per-line circle")
          .style("opacity", "1");
        d3.selectAll(".mouse-per-line text")
          .style("opacity", "1");
      })
      .on('mousemove', function() { // mouse moving over canvas
        var mouse = d3.mouse(this);
        d3.select(".mouse-line")
          .attr("d", function() {
            var d = "M" + mouse[0] + "," + height;
            d += " " + mouse[0] + "," + 0;
            return d;
          });

        d3.selectAll(".mouse-per-line")
          .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
            console.log(width / mouse[0])
            var xDate = x.invert(mouse[0]),
              bisect = d3.bisector(function(d) {
                return d.date;
              }).right;
            idx = bisect(d.values, xDate);

            var beginning = 0,
              end = lines[i].getTotalLength(),
              target = null;

            while (true) {
              target = Math.floor((beginning + end) / 2);
              pos = lines[i].getPointAtLength(target);
              if ((target === end || target === beginning) && pos.x !== mouse[0]) {
                break;
              }
              if (pos.x > mouse[0]) end = target;
              else if (pos.x < mouse[0]) beginning = target;
              else break; //position found
            }

            d3.select(this).select('text')
              .text(y.invert(pos.y).toFixed(2));

            return "translate(" + mouse[0] + "," + pos.y + ")";
          });
      });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="d3@3.5.3" data-semver="3.5.3" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.3/d3.js"></script>
  <style>
    body {
      font: 10px sans-serif;
    }
    .axis path,
    .axis line {
      fill: none;
      stroke: #000;
      shape-rendering: crispEdges;
    }
    .x.axis path {
      display: none;
    }
    .line {
      fill: none;
      stroke: steelblue;
      stroke-width: 1.5px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <script>
    var myData = "date New York San Francisco Austin\n\
20111001 63.4 62.7 72.2\n\
20111002 58.0 59.9 67.7\n\
20111003 53.3 59.1 69.4\n\
20111004 55.7 58.8 68.0\n\
20111005 64.2 58.7 72.4\n\
20111006 58.8 57.0 77.0\n\
20111007 57.9 56.7 82.3\n\
20111008 61.8 56.8 78.9\n\
20111009 69.3 56.7 68.8\n\
20111010 71.2 60.1 68.7\n\
20111011 68.7 61.1 70.3\n\
20111012 61.8 61.5 75.3\n\
20111013 63.0 64.3 76.6\n\
20111014 66.9 67.1 66.6\n\
20111015 61.7 64.6 68.0\n\
20111016 61.8 61.6 70.6\n\
20111017 62.8 61.1 71.1\n\
20111018 60.8 59.2 70.0\n\
20111019 62.1 58.9 61.6\n\
20111020 65.1 57.2 57.4\n\
20111021 55.6 56.4 64.3\n\
20111022 54.4 60.7 72.4\n";

    var margin = {
        top: 20,
        right: 80,
        bottom: 30,
        left: 50
      },
      width = 500 - margin.left - margin.right,
      height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y%m%d").parse;

    var x = d3.time.scale()
      .range([0, width]);

    var y = d3.scale.linear()
      .range([height, 0]);

    var color = d3.scale.category20();

    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(x)
      .orient("bottom");

    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(y)
      .orient("left");

    var line = d3.svg.line()
      .interpolate("basis")
      .x(function(d) {
        return x(d.date);
      })
      .y(function(d) {
        return y(d.temperature);
      });

    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
      .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
      .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    var data = d3.tsv.parse(myData);

    color.domain(d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key) {
      return key !== "date";
    }));

    data.forEach(function(d) {
      d.date = parseDate(d.date);
    });

    var cities = color.domain().map(function(name) {
      return {
        name: name,
        values: data.map(function(d) {
          return {
            date: d.date,
            temperature: +d[name]
          };
        })
      };
    });

    x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) {
      return d.date;
    }));

    y.domain([
      d3.min(cities, function(c) {
        return d3.min(c.values, function(v) {
          return v.temperature;
        });
      }),
      d3.max(cities, function(c) {
        return d3.max(c.values, function(v) {
          return v.temperature;
        });
      })
    ]);

    var legend = svg.selectAll('g')
      .data(cities)
      .enter()
      .append('g')
      .attr('class', 'legend');

    legend.append('rect')
      .attr('x', width - 20)
      .attr('y', function(d, i) {
        return i * 20;
      })
      .attr('width', 10)
      .attr('height', 10)
      .style('fill', function(d) {
        return color(d.name);
      });

    legend.append('text')
      .attr('x', width - 8)
      .attr('y', function(d, i) {
        return (i * 20) + 9;
      })
      .text(function(d) {
        return d.name;
      });

    svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

    svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
      .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Temperature (ºF)");

    var city = svg.selectAll(".city")
      .data(cities)
      .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "city");

    city.append("path")
      .attr("class", "line")
      .attr("d", function(d) {
        return line(d.values);
      })
      .style("stroke", function(d) {
        return color(d.name);
      });

    city.append("text")
      .datum(function(d) {
        return {
          name: d.name,
          value: d.values[d.values.length - 1]
        };
      })
      .attr("transform", function(d) {
        return "translate(" + x(d.value.date) + "," + y(d.value.temperature) + ")";
      })
      .attr("x", 3)
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .text(function(d) {
        return d.name;
      });

    var mouseG = svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "mouse-over-effects");

    mouseG.append("path") // this is the black vertical line to follow mouse
      .attr("class", "mouse-line")
      .style("stroke", "black")
      .style("stroke-width", "1px")
      .style("opacity", "0");

    var lines = document.getElementsByClassName('line');

    var mousePerLine = mouseG.selectAll('.mouse-per-line')
      .data(cities)
      .enter()
      .append("g")
      .attr("class", "mouse-per-line");

    mousePerLine.append("circle")
      .attr("r", 7)
      .style("stroke", function(d) {
        return color(d.name);
      })
      .style("fill", "none")
      .style("stroke-width", "1px")
      .style("opacity", "0");

    mousePerLine.append("text")
      .attr("transform", "translate(10,3)");

    mouseG.append('svg:rect') // append a rect to catch mouse movements on canvas
      .attr('width', width) // can't catch mouse events on a g element
      .attr('height', height)
      .attr('fill', 'none')
      .attr('pointer-events', 'all')
      .on('mouseout', function() { // on mouse out hide line, circles and text
        d3.select(".mouse-line")
          .style("opacity", "0");
        d3.selectAll(".mouse-per-line circle")
          .style("opacity", "0");
        d3.selectAll(".mouse-per-line text")
          .style("opacity", "0");
      })
      .on('mouseover', function() { // on mouse in show line, circles and text
        d3.select(".mouse-line")
          .style("opacity", "1");
        d3.selectAll(".mouse-per-line circle")
          .style("opacity", "1");
        d3.selectAll(".mouse-per-line text")
          .style("opacity", "1");
      })
      .on('mousemove', function() { // mouse moving over canvas
        var mouse = d3.mouse(this);
        d3.select(".mouse-line")
          .attr("d", function() {
            var d = "M" + mouse[0] + "," + height;
            d += " " + mouse[0] + "," + 0;
            return d;
          });

        d3.selectAll(".mouse-per-line")
          .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
            console.log(width / mouse[0])
            var xDate = x.invert(mouse[0]),
              bisect = d3.bisector(function(d) {
                return d.date;
              }).right;
            idx = bisect(d.values, xDate);

            var beginning = 0,
              end = lines[i].getTotalLength(),
              target = null;

            while (true) {
              target = Math.floor((beginning + end) / 2);
              pos = lines[i].getPointAtLength(target);
              if ((target === end || target === beginning) && pos.x !== mouse[0]) {
                break;
              }
              if (pos.x > mouse[0]) end = target;
              else if (pos.x < mouse[0]) beginning = target;
              else break; //position found
            }

            d3.select(this).select('text')
              .text(y.invert(pos.y).toFixed(2));

            return "translate(" + mouse[0] + "," + pos.y + ")";
          });
      });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: After thinking a lot, I can now show the data on mouse hover inside a rectangle for individual data but I want to show all the data inside a single rectangle rather than multiple rectangles for each data. Please help me with some tips or suggestions.