# D3 v7 Stacked Area Graph Tooltip Implementation

Tags: javascript, d3.js, tooltip, stacked-area-chart

I am pretty new to D3 and as the title says I am trying to implement a D3 stacked area chart similar to [Stacked area graph example](https://observablehq.com/@d3/stacked-area-chart).

However, I am by no means a D3 expert and am having a hard time trying to get a vertical line with tooltips to show up for each value, like how nvd3 has done it in [NVD3 stacked area graph example](https://nvd3.org/examples/stackedArea.html). Unfortunately, a lot of the examples I have seen seem to be using older versions of D3, and I don't feel they are necessarily implemented properly or translate well to a v7 solution.
Found Examples:
[Show the tooltip inside a div in a D3 stacked area chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38342931/show-the-tooltip-inside-a-div-in-a-d3-stacked-area-chart)
[d3: how to focus separate tooltips for stacked area chart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70309210/d3-how-to-focus-separate-tooltips-for-stacked-area-chart)

I was able to find the [D3 line chart with tooltip example](https://observablehq.com/@d3/line-with-tooltip) and think it could be modified pretty easily to work with the stacked area graph example mentioned previously.

```
StackedAreaChart(data, eventData, {
        x = ([x]) => x, // given d in data, returns the (ordinal) x-value
        y = ([, y]) => y, // given d in data, returns the (quantitative) y-value
        z = () => 1, // given d in data, returns the (categorical) z-value
        title, // given d in data, returns the title text
        marginTop = 20, // top margin, in pixels
        marginRight = 30, // right margin, in pixels
        marginBottom = 30, // bottom margin, in pixels
        marginLeft = 40, // left margin, in pixels
        width = 910, // outer width, in pixels
        height = 400, // outer height, in pixels
        xType = d3.scaleUtc, // type of x-scale
        xDomain, // [xmin, xmax]
        xRange = [marginLeft, width - marginRight], // [left, right]
        yType = d3.scaleLinear, // type of y-scale
        yDomain, // [ymin, ymax]
        yRange = [height - marginBottom, marginTop], // [bottom, top]
        zDomain, // array of z-values
        offset = d3.stackOffsetDiverging, // stack offset method
        order = d3.stackOrderNone, // stack order method
        xFormat, // a format specifier string for the x-axis
        yFormat, // a format specifier for the y-axis
        yLabel, // a label for the y-axis
        colors = d3.schemeTableau10 // array of colors for z
    } = {}) {

    // Compute values.
    const X = d3.map(data, x);
    const Y = d3.map(data, y);
    const Z = d3.map(data, z);

    // console.log("X: ", X);
    // console.log("Y: ", Y);
    // console.log("Z; ", Z);
    // console.log("colors: ", colors);

    // Compute default x- and z-domains, and unique the z-domain.
    if (xDomain === undefined) xDomain = d3.extent(X);
    if (zDomain === undefined) zDomain = Z;
    zDomain = new d3.InternSet(zDomain);

    // console.log("y: ", y);
    // console.log("zDomain: ", zDomain);

    // Omit any data not present in the z-domain.
    const I = d3.range(X.length).filter(i => zDomain.has(Z[i]));
    //  console.log("I: ", I );
    // Compute a nested array of series where each series is [[y1, y2], [y1, y2],
    // [y1, y2], …] representing the y-extent of each stacked rect. In addition,
    // each tuple has an i (index) property so that we can refer back to the
    // original data point (data[i]). This code assumes that there is only one
    // data point for a given unique x- and z-value.
    const series = d3.stack()
        .keys(zDomain)
        .value(([x, I], z) => Y[I.get(z)])
        .order(order)
        .offset(offset)
        (d3.rollup(I, ([i]) => i, i => X[i], i => Z[i]))
        .map(s => s.map(d => Object.assign(d, {i: d.data[1].get(s.key)})));

    // console.log("series: ", series)

    // Compute the default y-domain. Note: diverging stacks can be negative.
    if (yDomain === undefined) yDomain = d3.extent(series.flat(2));

    // Construct scales and axes.
    const xScale = xType(xDomain, xRange);
    const yScale = yType(yDomain, yRange);
    const color = d3.scaleOrdinal(zDomain, colors);
    const xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale).ticks(width / 80, xFormat).tickSizeOuter(0);
    const yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yScale).ticks(height / 50, yFormat);

    // console.log("xScale: ", xScale)
    // console.log("yScale: ", yScale)
    // console.log("color: ", color)
    // console.log("xAxis: ", xAxis)
    // console.log("yAxis: ", yAxis)

    const area = d3.area()
        .x(({i}) => xScale(X[i]))
        .y0(([y1]) => yScale(y1))
        .y1(([, y2]) => yScale(y2));

    const svg = d3.select("#stacked_area_chart").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height)
        .attr("viewBox", [0, 0, width, height])
        .attr("style", "max-width: 100%; height: auto; height: intrinsic;")
        .on("pointerenter pointermove", pointermoved)
        .on("pointerleave", pointerleft)
        .on("touchstart", event => event.preventDefault());

    // console.log("svg: ", svg)
    svg.append("g")
        .attr("transform", `translate(${marginLeft},0)`)
        .call(yAxis)
        .call(g => g.select(".domain").remove())
        .call(g => g.selectAll(".tick line").clone()
            .attr("x2", width - marginLeft - marginRight)
            .attr("stroke-opacity", 0.1))
        .call(g => g.append("text")
            .attr("x", -marginLeft)
            .attr("y", 10)
            .attr("fill", "currentColor")
            .attr("text-anchor", "start")
            .text(yLabel));

    // console.log("svg2: ", svg)
    svg.append("g")
        .attr('id', 'graphArea')
        .selectAll("path")
        .data(series)
        .join("path")
        .attr("fill", ([{i}]) => color(Z[i]))
        .attr("d", area)
        .append("title");
        

    // console.log(xAxis);

    svg.append("g")
        .attr("transform", `translate(0,${height - marginBottom})`)
        .call(xAxis);
    
    //applies the vertical event lines
    var eventLine = d3.select('#graphArea');
    eventLine.selectAll("lines")
        .data(eventData)
        .enter()
        .append('line')
          .attr("y1", height - 30)
          .attr("y2", 20)
          .attr("x1", d => xAxis.scale()(d.date))
          .attr("x2", d => xAxis.scale()(d.date))
          .style("stroke-width", 2)
          .style("stroke", "black")
          .style("opacity", .5)
    
    //appends labels to the vertical event lines
    eventLine.append("g")
      .selectAll("text")
      .data(eventData)
      .enter()
      .append("text")
      .attr("x", d => xAxis.scale()(d.date))
      .attr("y", 15)
      .style("font-size","10px")
      .text(d => d.event);


    // Compute titles.
      if (title === undefined) {
        const formatDate = xScale.tickFormat(null, "%Y");
        const formatValue = yScale.tickFormat(100, yFormat);
        title = i => `${(Z[i])}\n${Y[i]}`;
      } else {
        const O = d3.map(data, d => d);
        const T = title;
        title = i => T(O[i], i, data);
      }
    
    //adds tooltip to each area
    const tooltip = svg.append("g")
          .style("pointer-events", "none");

    function pointermoved(event) {
        const i = d3.bisectCenter(X, xScale.invert(d3.pointer(event)[0]));
        tooltip.style("display", null);
        tooltip.attr("transform", `translate(${xScale(X[i])},${yScale(Y[i])})`);

        console.log(`${title(i)}`.split(/\n/));

        const path = tooltip.selectAll("path")
          .data(data)
          .join("path")
            .attr("fill", "white")
            .attr("stroke", "black");

        const text = tooltip.selectAll("text")
          .data(data)
          .join("text")
          .call(text => text
            .selectAll("tspan")
            .data(`${title(i)}`.split(/\n/))
            .join("tspan")
              .attr("x", 0)
              .attr("y", (_, i) => `${i * 1.1}em`)
              .attr("font-weight", (_, i) => i ? null : "bold")
              .text(d => d.node));

        const {x, y, width: w, height: h} = text.node().getBBox();
        text.attr("transform", `translate(${-w / 2},${15 - y})`);
        path.attr("d", `M${-w / 2 - 10},5H-5l5,-5l5,5H${w / 2 + 10}v${h + 20}h-${w + 20}z`);
        // svg.property("value", O[i]).dispatch("input", {bubbles: true});
      }

      function pointerleft() {
        tooltip.style("display", "none");
        svg.node().value = null;
        svg.dispatch("input", {bubbles: true});
      }
     
    return Object.assign(svg.node(), {scales: {color}});
    }
  }
```

Extracted Tooltip code

```
//adds tooltip to each area
    const tooltip = svg.append("g")
          .style("pointer-events", "none");

    function pointermoved(event) {
        const i = d3.bisectCenter(X, xScale.invert(d3.pointer(event)[0]));
        tooltip.style("display", null);
        tooltip.attr("transform", `translate(${xScale(X[i])},${yScale(Y[i])})`);

        console.log(`${title(i)}`.split(/\n/));

        const path = tooltip.selectAll("path")
          .data(data)
          .join("path")
            .attr("fill", "white")
            .attr("stroke", "black");

        const text = tooltip.selectAll("text")
          .data(data)
          .join("text")
          .call(text => text
            .selectAll("tspan")
            .data(`${title(i)}`.split(/\n/))
            .join("tspan")
              .attr("x", 0)
              .attr("y", (_, i) => `${i * 1.1}em`)
              .attr("font-weight", (_, i) => i ? null : "bold")
              .text(d => d.node));

        const {x, y, width: w, height: h} = text.node().getBBox();
        text.attr("transform", `translate(${-w / 2},${15 - y})`);
        path.attr("d", `M${-w / 2 - 10},5H-5l5,-5l5,5H${w / 2 + 10}v${h + 20}h-${w + 20}z`);
        // svg.property("value", O[i]).dispatch("input", {bubbles: true});
      }

      function pointerleft() {
        tooltip.style("display", "none");
        svg.node().value = null;
        svg.dispatch("input", {bubbles: true});
      }
```

Data sample

```
areaChartData: {
        nodeData: [
            {node: 'rti-dds-subscriber', percentConsumption: 15, date: new Date('2021-04-23')},
            {node: 'rti-dds-publisher', percentConsumption: 25, date: new Date('2021-04-23')},
            {node: 'openDDS-publisher', percentConsumption: 25, date: new Date('2021-04-23')},
            {node:'osi-dds-publisher', percentConsumption: 15, date: new Date('2021-04-23')},
            {node: 'osi-dds-subscriber', percentConsumption: 20, date: new Date('2021-04-23')},
            {node: 'rti-dds-subscriber', percentConsumption: 20, date: new Date('2022-04-23')},
            {node: 'rti-dds-publisher', percentConsumption: 20, date: new Date('2022-04-23')},
            {node: 'openDDS-publisher', percentConsumption: 30, date: new Date('2022-04-23')},
            {node:'osi-dds-publisher', percentConsumption: 20, date: new Date('2022-04-23')},
            {node: 'osi-dds-subscriber', percentConsumption: 10, date: new Date('2022-04-23')},
            {node: 'rti-dds-subscriber', percentConsumption: 30, date: new Date('2023-04-23')},
            {node: 'rti-dds-publisher', percentConsumption: 20, date: new Date('2023-04-23')},
            {node: 'openDDS-publisher', percentConsumption: 10, date: new Date('2023-04-23')},
            {node:'osi-dds-publisher', percentConsumption: 25, date: new Date('2023-04-23')},
            {node: 'osi-dds-subscriber', percentConsumption: 15, date: new Date('2023-04-23')},
            {node: 'rti-dds-subscriber', percentConsumption: 10, date: new Date('2024-04-23')},
            {node: 'rti-dds-publisher', percentConsumption: 10, date: new Date('2024-04-23')},
            {node: 'openDDS-publisher', percentConsumption: 60, date: new Date('2024-04-23')},
            {node:'osi-dds-publisher', percentConsumption: 10, date: new Date('2024-04-23')},
            {node: 'osi-dds-subscriber', percentConsumption: 10, date: new Date('2024-04-23')},
            {node: 'rti-dds-subscriber', percentConsumption: 30, date: new Date('2025-04-23')},
            {node: 'rti-dds-publisher', percentConsumption: 10, date: new Date('2025-04-23')},
            {node: 'openDDS-publisher', percentConsumption: 25, date: new Date('2025-04-23')},
            {node:'osi-dds-publisher', percentConsumption: 20, date: new Date('2025-04-23')},
            {node: 'osi-dds-subscriber', percentConsumption: 15, date: new Date('2025-04-23')}
        ],
        eventData: [
          {event: 'Ddos Test', date: new Date('2023')},
          {event: 'Bad Actor 1 Test', date: new Date('2025')}
        ]
      }
```

Function call

```
   this.StackedAreaChart(areaChartData.nodeData, areaChartData.eventData, {
        x: d => d.date,
        y: d => d.percentConsumption,
        z: d => d.node,
        yLabel: "% Energy Consumption",
        width: 800,
        height: 350
    })
```

Here is a link code pen, but it is broken and don't really have enough experience with it to get it working... [codepen](https://codepen.io/stavrosi/pen/vYdMORx?editors=1112)